# How to find the next document in MongoDB using node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

Ideally, I would like to be able to compare data from the cursor object and the following cursor.next() object in order to perform other functions.

The following code results in the `nextDoc` (or `nextState`) being undefined.

```
    var data = db.collection('data');

    var myCursor = data.find({});
    myCursor.sort({'State': 1, 'Temperature': -1});

    var nextDoc = myCursor.nextObject( function (err, doc) {
        if (err) throw err;
    });

    myCursor.each( function (err, doc) {
        if(err) throw err;
        if(doc == null) {
            return db.close();
        }

        var currState = doc.State;
        var nextState = nextDoc;

        console.log("currState:" + currState + " nextState:" + nextState);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Well if you think about it, asking for the "next" document really does not make that much sense as soon enough in your execution you are going to hit the "end" of the query results and there just will not be a "next".

Therefore the better approach is to "keep" the "last" result and then compare to the current item. The logic is also quite simple as the very first has nothing to compare to, so there is little point. But everything else works fine.

A preferce here is to use  the [stream interface](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html) which is natively presented in the latest driver (otherwise call `.stream()` ), as there is a bit more control here in case you might want to do other things such as an `.update()` or other async operation:

```
var data = db.collection('data');

var myCursor = data.find({});
myCursor.sort({'State': 1, 'Temperature': -1});

var prevState = null;

myCursor.on("err",function(err) {
    throw err;
});

myCursor.on("end",function() {
    db.close();
});

myCursor.on("data",function(data) {
    myCursor.pause();             // stops other events emitting

    if ( prevState != null ) {
       console.log("prevState: %s currState %s",prevState,data.State);
    }
    prevState = data.State;

    myCursor.resume();            // Restart when finsihed with document
});
```

The `.pause()` and `.resume()` methods there make sure that the variable outside of the scope is respected with each iteration as no more "data" events are emitted until resumed.

Of course if you did do an asynchronous process then the `.resume()` should be called within it's callback function to ensure the "loop" does not continue until that processing is complete.

Therefore it is just looking at the problem the other way around, and look back not forwards, which is something cursors and streams happily do.

Comment: I ended up doing something like this:

doc.forEach(function (docs) {

        if(newstate != docs.State) {

            newstate = docs.State;
            query['_id'] = docs['_id'];
            var operator = { '$set' : { 'month_high' : true } };
            db.collection('data').update(query, operator, function(err, updated) {
                if(err) throw err;
                console.dir("Successfully updated " + updated + " document!");

            });   
        }

Comment: Where `var newstate = "";` in a previous line